# how make my vb.net website work in offline with Manifest file

Tags: vb.net

Sorry guys but the manifest things is really new to me, i had tried to google it for few days but have no idea exactly what to do. I am trying to add the manifest file to my existing 'ASPX' file vb.net website so that i can make it work offline, anyone could help i will be appreciate..

i even follow a website to try to simulate with C# but fail as well
above is my manifest file look like

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# v1
# Root Path: 

CACHE:
# Jquery Libraries
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js

# Site Content
About.html
Index.html

NETWORK:
http://*
https://*
```

and this is my simulate html file look like..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="Manifest.ashx" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hi About</h1>
    <a href="Index.html">Index</a>
</body>
</html>
```

when i run the code, no error but when i stop IIS and run it become 404 and got no idea how to fix this.